# Comparar valores de atributos almacenados en ArrayList como Objetos de instancias de clases

Tags: java, java-8

estoy creando un programara para generar una serie de datos para mi empresa, el problema que tengo es el siguiente, al momento de cargar los datos de una consulta sql a un arraylist por medio de la estructura de una clase, lo que necesito es acceder a ellos uno por uno comparándolos con otros datos de otro arraylist de otra consulta sql, esto es para verificar, que datos están repetidos en las dos consultas, YA PROBE CON EL METODO .get() del objeto arraylist, pero me retorna un hashcode que la verdad no se majear.
este es mi código

```
public class LoadData {

private static String company;
private static String date_init;
private static String date_end;

protected static ArrayList modifiedPrice;
protected static ArrayList<ModelModifiedSKU> modifiedSKU;
protected static ArrayList<ModelScaleX06> scaleX06;
protected static ArrayList<ModelScaleX12> scaleX12;
protected static ArrayList<ModelScaleX12X06> scaleX06X12;

protected LoadData() {
}

public LoadData(String date_init, String date_end, String company) {
    LoadData.date_init = date_init;
    LoadData.date_end = date_end;
    LoadData.company = company;
}

public boolean loadModifiedPrice(boolean confirmation) throws SQLException {
    Statement st = ConfigurationDB.connectionStatic.createStatement();
    ModelModifiedPrice mp1 = new ModelModifiedPrice();
    ResultSet rs;
    modifiedPrice = new ArrayList();
    try {
        //Ejecutar consulta SQL
        rs = st.executeQuery(mp1.query());
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Agregar datos al ArrayList modifiedPrice con la clase modelo ModelModifiedPrice
            ModelModifiedPrice mp2 = new ModelModifiedPrice();
            mp2.setPr1cod(rs.getInt("pr1cod"));
            mp2.setInvptmdesc(rs.getString("invptmdesc").toString());
            mp2.setPr1diq(rs.getFloat("pr1diq"));
            modifiedPrice.add(mp2);

        }
        st.close();
        rs.close();
        int x = modifiedPrice.size();
        //COMO PUEDO ACCEDER A LOS DATOS DE MI ARRAYLIST modifiedPrice Y COMPARARLOS CON OTROS DATOS
        //DE OTRO ARRYLIST


        

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Para comparar objetos, necesitas implementar el método `equals` y el método `hashCode`. Si usas un IDE (como Eclipse, Netbeans o IntelliJ) existen funcionalidades para crear este tipo de métodos automáticamente.

Answer (score 0):

ya he encontrado una manera de extraer datos de un arrylist de objetos y poder compararlo con otros arraylist de objetos, es solo el código para extraer los datos del array, la comparación no es tan complicada.

```
ModelModifiedPrice mmd1;
        Iterator iter =  modifiedPrice.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            int num = 0;
            mmd1 = (ModelModifiedPrice)iter.next();
            num = mmd1.getPr1cod();
        }
```